# SharePoint 2019 blog classic experience - How do I increase this page size to 15 comments

Tags: 2019, blog, comments

We have a blog (Classic experience) in a SharePoint 2019 on-premises. If I open an article within the blog, it only displays 10 comments before I have to page to the next 10 comments. How do I increase this page size to 15 or 20?

I found a post here which asked about the same question, but I Couldn't figure out, where I have to use that code.

---

**The answer was**:

You could directly access the backfield `m_displayItems` instead of using the property `DisplayItems`:

```
FieldInfo fi = typeof(SocialCommentControl).GetField("m_displayItems", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
fi.SetValue(CommentControl, 1000);
```

This way you can use a value greater than 10 (which is restricted in the property setter).

---

I would need help, where I can find that file to edit and where to put it in?

Thank you very much in advance.